# What if Remove page from Google index after the new search console update?

Tags: google, google-search-console, google-search, google-index, content

[image: google search console]

According to the new update in search console, url can be temporarily remove for 6 months or less as 3 month. Can be removed permanently from site also.

I have pages that already indexed and ranked. The pages also have amount of visitor. But now don't want to have those pages on site. Want to delete.

After deleting Will it remove from Google also. Whereas the pages indexed approx 2 years ago...

Comment: The new search console update didn't change the way this tool works.  It just changed how it looks a bit.

Answer (score 2):

That tool is explicitly what you stated - that the URL can be *temporarily* removed.

The best way to permanently remove pages from your site is delete the content and have the server return a `404 not found`, or even better, `410 gone` response code. When Google (or other search engines) crawl the site again, they will take note of the URLs returning these codes and update their indices by not including them in the new version.

Now, after you delete these pages and return the 4XX status codes, to speed things up *you could* go directly to the [remove outdated content](https://search.google.com/search-console/removals) tool. You add the URL of the page that no longer exists, Google will check to make sure that it indeed does not exist, and then will remove it from the results pages.